# Change object property in nested list based on a keyword

Tags: c#, system.reactive, xamarin

I have these classes:

```
public class BaseSearchFilter
{
    public int IssueCount { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public string FilterDescription { get; set; }
}

public class IssueTypeSearchFilter : BaseSearchFilter
{
    public StandardIssueTypeDTO IssueType { get; set; }
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }
}

public class GroupedIssueTypeSearchFilter : ReactiveObject
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryTitle { get; set; }

    int selectionCode;
    public int SelectionCode
    {
        get { return selectionCode; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref selectionCode, value); }
    }

    public ReactiveList<IssueTypeSearchFilter> IssueTypeFilterList { get; set; }
}
```

I also have `AllGroupedStandardIssueTypesFilter` which is a list of `GroupedIssueTypeSearchFilter` and the value will be something like this:

```
[0]:
  CategoryID = 1;
  CategoryTitle = "Test A";
  SelectionCode = 1;
  IssueTypeFilterList =
      [0]: 
         IssueType = //some value
         IsVisible = false;
         IssueCount = 23;
         IsSelected = false;
         FilterDescription = "some description"
      [1]: 
         IssueType = //some value
         IsVisible = false;
         IssueCount = 10;
         IsSelected = true;
         FilterDescription = "some description"
      [and so on...]
[1]:
  CategoryID = 3;
  CategoryTitle = "New Title";
  SelectionCode = 2;
  IssueTypeFilterList =
      [0]: 
         IssueType = //some value
         IsVisible = false;
         IssueCount = 4;
         IsSelected = false;
         FilterDescription = "some description"
      [1]: 
         IssueType = //some value
         IsVisible = false;
         IssueCount = 2;
         IsSelected = false;
         FilterDescription = "some description"
      [and so on...]
[and so on...]
```

I need to filter `AllGroupedStandardIssueTypesFilter` based on a keyword (`string`).

For example, if the keyword is `"New"`, I need to find all objects in `IssueTypeFilterList.IssueType` that contain the keyword and change its `IsVisible` property to `true` and the rest to `false`.

This is the function that I created to filter `AllGroupedStandardIssueTypesFilter`:

```
FilterIssueType = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(async x =>
{
    Func<IssueTypeSearchFilter, bool> filterFunc = d =>
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.IssueTypeSearchQuery) ? true :
        d.IssueType.Title.ToLower().Contains(this.IssueTypeSearchQuery.ToLower()) ||
        d.IssueType.CategoryTitle.ToLower().Contains(this.IssueTypeSearchQuery.ToLower()) ||
        d.IssueCount.ToString().Contains(this.IssueTypeSearchQuery);

    var filteredStdIssueTypes = AllStandardIssueTypesFilter.Where(filterFunc);

    Func<GroupedIssueTypeSearchFilter, bool> filterFunc1 = d =>
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.IssueTypeSearchQuery) ? true :
        d.IssueTypeFilterList.Any(a => a.IssueType.Title.ToLower().Contains(this.IssueTypeSearchQuery.ToLower())) ||
        d.IssueTypeFilterList.Any(b => b.IssueType.CategoryTitle.ToLower().Contains(this.IssueTypeSearchQuery.ToLower())) ||
        d.IssueTypeFilterList.Any(c => c.IssueCount.ToString().Contains(this.IssueTypeSearchQuery.ToLower()));

    var filteredGroupedStdIssueTypes = AllGroupedStandardIssueTypesFilter.Where(filterFunc1);

    for (int i = 0; i < filteredGroupedStdIssueTypes.Count(); i++)
    {
        var result = filteredStdIssueTypes.Where(dd => dd.IssueType.CategoryId == filteredGroupedStdIssueTypes.ElementAt(i).CategoryID);
        var notInFilteredResult = filteredGroupedStdIssueTypes.ElementAt(i).IssueTypeFilterList.Except(result).ToList();
        foreach(IssueTypeSearchFilter issue in notInFilteredResult)
        {
            issue.IsVisible = false;
        }
        var filteredResult = filteredGroupedStdIssueTypes.ElementAt(i).IssueTypeFilterList.Except(notInFilteredResult).ToList();
        foreach (IssueTypeSearchFilter issue in filteredResult)
        {
            issue.IsVisible = true;
        }
    }

    return await Task.FromResult(filteredGroupedStdIssueTypes);
});
```

Is there any improvement that I could do to that filter function?

Answer (score 2):

Properly name everything: `filterFunc` and (even worse) `filterFunc1` aren't informative at all.

---

Don't do this:

```
a.IssueType.Title.ToLower().Contains(this.IssueTypeSearchQuery.ToLower())
```

If you need a case insensitive Contains, write a helper method:

```
    private bool Contains(string source, string filter)
    {
        return source.IndexOf(filter, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0;
    }
```

You could also turn this into an extension method, of course.

---

Note that your code isn't consistent:

```
d.IssueCount.ToString().Contains(this.IssueTypeSearchQuery);
```

vs:

```
c.IssueCount.ToString().Contains(this.IssueTypeSearchQuery.ToLower()));
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> FilterIssueType = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(async x =>
> {
>      ....
> }
> ```

You have big lambda here with even more nested lambdas. Consider refactoring this into separate filter methods that you can test and maintain independantly.

---

> ```
> filteredStdIssueTypes.Where(dd => dd.IssueType.CategoryId == filteredGroupedStdIssueTypes.ElementAt(i).CategoryID);
> ```

You use ids here to get matching elements from the other collection so most probably a join like this would be more efficient and easier to read.

```
var joined = 
    from x in filteredStdIssueTypes
    join y in filteredGroupedStdIssueTypes on x.IssueType.CategoryId equals y.CategoryID
    select new { x, y };
```

---

In your loop you call

> ```
> filteredStdIssueTypes.Where
> ```

on each iteration but you don't store the results of the previous filtering as a list or an array.

> ```
> var filteredGroupedStdIssueTypes = AllGroupedStandardIssueTypesFilter.Where(filterFunc1);
> ```

```
// no .ToList() or .ToArray()
```

this means that the filter runs over and over agian on each iteration. If there are a lot of items to filter it might be huge performance hit.